# Visual Studio 2017 - Windows Forms - how to set exe icon - Visual C++

Tags: icons, visual-studio-2017, exe

I'm trying to set exe file icon. In VS 2010 it was simple in properties. Did you know how to do it in VS2017? It's impossible to find it for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to add new icon at time of Loading [not in constructor] as below.
1. Click the design form like MyForm.h [Design]
2. In Properties window, click "Events" tab (lightning symbol)
3. Goto "Load" method and double click the empty column that opens up xxxxx_Load function (in my case "MJCal_Load" below)
4. Add two lines as mine below with your icon name (can be full name)

```
private: System::Void MJCal_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    Drawing::Icon ^myIcon = gcnew Drawing::Icon("calc.ico");
    this->Icon = myIcon;
}
```

Good luck,
Meung Kim